# Can a function has an argument like (x | y)? How does it work?

Tags: c++, function, opencv, input, arguments

I was reading OpenCV library functions that I encountered to this function:

```
void cv::logPolar(
cv::InputArray src,
cv::OutputArray dst,
cv::Point2f center,
double m,
int flags = cv::INTER_LINEAR | cv::WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS
);
```

In last argument (flag) it takes two inputs at the same time separated by `|` . How is it possible and How does it work?

Comment: lookup [Bitwise-OR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators)

Comment: the `=` is for default argument, `|` is just the bitwise operator, `cv::INTER_LINEAR` and `cv::WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS` are probably just flags that are combined through the `|`

Comment: I don't think it's a duplicate.  The OP of *this* question needs to understand *both* the problem that the OP of the suggested duplicate had, *and* default arguments.

Comment: @MartinBonner In its current state, this question does not mention any issue with default arguments, it just happens to be part of the example.

Comment: @Hasani If the duplicate does not answer your question, feel free to comment why, and maybe edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Thank you guys, I got my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` is a [bitwise OR](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_arithmetic#Bitwise_logic_operators) operation performed between two flags `cv::INTER_LINEAR` and `cv::WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS`.

According to the [OpenCV documentation](https://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html), the value of `cv::INTER_LINEAR` is `1(binary : 0001 )` and that of `cv::WAR_FILL_OUTLIERS` is `8(binary : 1000 )`.

Therefore, the bitwise OR operation on them would provide a result of `1001` or 9 in decimal.

This is provided as a default argument to the function parameter `flags`.